# Error caracteres extraños XML y Django

Tags: django, xml

Saludos estoy generando un XML  con Django el cual lo hace bien el problema surge cuando tengo acentos/tildes, etc me muestra algo asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<descripcion>Serv??cio de M??ntenimiento</descripcion>
....
...
```

Lo que uso para generar es:

```
render_to_string('formato_sri.xml', context_xml)
```

este **context_xml** tiene texto con acentos/tildes y otros caracteres especiales los mismos que se almacenan en la BD sin problema tan solo al colocarlos en el XML me muestra el simbolo "**??**".

Quiza alguna sugerencia gracias..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que al inicio de tu `views.py` setees la codificación UTF-8:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
```

Posteriormente, en la generación de la variable `context_xml` tendrás que hacer explícita su codificación, es decir, `context_xml.encode('utf-8)`. Comprueba que en la generación del contenido de esa variable se esté seteando ninguna otra codificación.

Answer (score 0):

por favor revisa la codificación de tu editor de texto, más de una vez ha pasado de tener codificacion ISO en el editor y UTF en el programa final y los caracteres salen asi.

Si no, siempre puedes cambiar la codificacion al vuelo con utf8_encode(),pero es innecesario.

Un saludo.